# Online Schema Modification

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called BigData on SQL Server. BigData is modified by an app continuously and can't  be taken offline even for a second. Another requirement is that the table can't be locked exclusively by some other process other than the app accessing it. The question is; how can I change one of the columns of BigData from Bigint to int? any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also recently had a question very similar to this during a PayPal interview.  This situation is common with a bank or e-commerce company which has a live database which is constantly in use.

The answer I gave was to:

1. Create a new table based on the `BigData` table which looks identical except that the column has the new type.
2. Create a trigger which will fire every time an update or insert is made to the old table.  The trigger will update/insert appropriately to the new table
3. Start copying all records from the old table to the new table which are older than the time the trigger goes live.  This step will be overlapping as the trigger covers the new records.
4. Once all the old records have successfully been copied to the new table, we can expect that the new table now has all legacy records, plus any new records which were inserted/updated since we started the migration process.

After doing this, the new and old tables should have identical content, and both should be in sync with the running application.  Now, the old table can be dropped, and the new table can be renamed to the old one.  It may be necessary for a brief outage (say a few minutes) to achieve this, but this should be acceptable.

Comment: Brilliant answer! One thing I forgot was the table have two billion records. Don't you think attempting to copy this table would result in locking the table?

Comment: In addition to your point, there is also the problem of making certain that all old records do eventually get copied after you have set up your triggers.  You might need to finesse things so that the old table does not get locked, but the general strategy seems correct to me.

Comment: I really like the answer and i would do the same since there is no other possibility I see. BTW, what your interview said on your answer. curious to know :)

Comment: This was the last question during a 30 minute data interview (one of several 30 minute sessions of various topics).  I nailed all the query questions and this was the last question.  After I finished giving the answer, it basically ended (meaning he was happy with my performance).

Comment: Unucky me :)  this was the first question i was asked it kind of botherd me afterwards

Comment: Nice answer but in between step 2 and 3 data might have been inserted to the original table. So perhaps the step afterwards would be to ensure this possible missing data is copied over to the new table.

Comment: @KavehHadjari I actually intend for steps 2 and 3 to be overlapping.  Only records which were created/updated before the trigger goes live would be candidates for copying.  Any new/updated records would be covered by the trigger.  Because of issues with locking the old table, copying might be done over a fairly long time.

Comment: In that case you would need to swap order of step 2 and 3 so the trigger is first created which copies the new data and then you would copy the old data.

Comment: @KavehHadjari I just did this, thanks for pointing out this edge case.

Comment: A solution for locking issues is to copy old data in batches with delays in between each batch to minimize issues with long running transaction.

Comment: @KavehHadjari This is exactly what I have in mind, though I did not mention it.  If the table has an identity column, we could use this to keep track of which records we have processed in each batch.

Comment: *"Now, the old table can be dropped, and the app can point to the new one."*. Renaming the new table to the old table name after dropping the old one, wouldn't that be better rather than changing the app (or many apps)?

Comment: @TT. Thanks for your vigilance.  This is what I had in mind, though I guess I did not articulate it well enough.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to avoid locking issues during a possibly long running processes of copying old data is to do it batches with delays in between each batch to allow other normal usage processes to lock the table in the delay between each batch. As @TimBiegeleisen also mentioned this could be simple if there's an identity column which is also primary key since then we can calculate the offset to which rows to copy from the old table and also we could split up the batches more efficiently based on the order of the identity. It's still a doable approach even without identity, at least if there's a primary key.